# Drools: Merged cells in CSV

Tags: csv, drools

I have a set of Drools rules stored in an Excel document that for various reasons needs to be replaced with a .csv file. The problem is that .csv files don't support merged cells, making it difficult if not impossible to properly convert the rules.

After a lot of googling, I found references to using "..." to indicate merged cells, but no explicit examples on how to use it. Documentation found in the source code gives a few more hints, but is still too ambiguous; I've tried countless different interpretations of it without any success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue as you. After reviewing their source code: CsvParser + DefaultRuleSheetListener, I found the solution. Here this post can help you to save time.

Only specify ... at ObjectType Matching row, i.e. the one below CONDTION, ACTION row. Starting from the begin of the Merged cell to the end of the merged cell. Please note, for the continued merged cell, you cannot just use "...", but the code will ignore it after normalized and trim and treat it as an empty cell and silently ignore it. Put anything such as a..., b..., etc. Here is the example.

Please also note Drools uses buffered reader, not CSV reader, it cannot handle one cell value spanning multiple lines. Unless you have your CSVParser which uses CSVReader.

Here is a simplified example.

```
CONDITION,CONDITION,CONDITION,ACTION,ACTION
$Client:Client(),$Product:Product()...,anythingButNotJust3Dots...,,
"clientType == ""$param""","planType == ""$param""","accountType == ""$param""","documents.add(""$param"");","documents.add(""$param"");"
INDIVIDUAL,RRSP,CASH,document1,document2
INDIVIDUAL,RESP,CASH,document2,
INDIVIDUAL,RIF,CASH,document3,
INDIVIDUAL,,MARGIN,document4,document6
```

Comment: While the system has been rewritten since asking the question and CSV files are no longer needed, I still appreciate the answer. Hopefully, it'll be of use to someone else in the future. :)